# modify autocomplete.js

Tags: jquery

i am trying to add a button in the autocomple.js when no match if found and it should allow the user to turn off autocomplete. i have added the button but i can not fire a event on the button click..
this is the code where i am trying to bind the mousedown event with the button

```
if (li.childNodes[x].tagName && li.childNodes[x].tagName == 'INPUT')
{
    (li.childNodes[x]).mousedown(function() {
        alert('finally');
    });
}
```

thanks in advance ..
cheers....
abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code in place of your snippet will do the trick:

```
if (li.childNodes[x].tagName && li.childNodes[x].tagName == 'INPUT') {
    $(li.childNodes[x]).click(function() {
        alert('finally');
    });
}
```

Note that I added the `$` on line 2 and bound to the `click` event instead of `mousedown`.